# "bash: alias: python-winpty python.exe: not found" error when staring GItbash on Windos

Tags: python

I am just starting with Python and after installing Gitbash and Anaconda I ran into this error "bash: alias: python-winpty python.exe: not found". There is also (base) that appears every time I run a command which I have no idea what is it referring to. One more thing is that I cannot run python even tho the command Python --version gives back the python version installed. Any help?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxedJ.png)

Comment: Enough information to solve your problem needs to be included in the question **as text**. For the reasons described in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), screenshots don't count.

Comment: Note that we need not just your error messages, but also the code that's being run to generate those errors. That may mean `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, or other shell configuration files as appropriate.

Comment: Hi @CharlesDuffy I get the mentioned error before running anything, could you please calrify?

Comment: Your shell is running something that its configuration files are telling it to run. We need to know what's in those configuration files to solve it.

Comment: To start a new copy of your shell and log what's happening while it starts up, runs `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE[0]}:$LINENO+' bash -xli`. We need those logs _included in the question itself_ **as text**.